# Convert string to time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

`2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00`

I am trying to convert this string to a date. It should equal `2019-02-27 22:15` as I want to subtract the 8 hours.
How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you need convert to UTC timezone?

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp('2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00').tz_convert("UTC") # Timestamp('2019-02-27 22:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `tz=None`, we can remove the timezone (after converting to UTC if necessary) with [`Timestamp.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html), if necessary convert values to datetimes:

```
a = '2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00'
b = pd.to_datetime(a).tz_convert(None)
print (b)
2019-02-27 22:15:00
```

If column in DataFrame use [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00','2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.tz_convert(None)
print (df)
                 date
0 2019-02-27 22:15:00
1 2019-02-27 22:15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import pandas as pd
d = '2019-02-28 06:15 +08:00'
pd.to_datetime(d).tz_convert('UTC')

Timestamp('2019-02-27 22:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```